# Gaming laptop temps a bit high?

Tags: laptop, cooling, overheating, laptop-cooler

I have an MSi GT70 Dragon Edition 2. Whilst playing Battlefield 4, my GPU and 'Temp1' (SpeedFan) show results of it being up to 80c. Is this too hot for it? And if so, should I get a laptop cooling pad? One more, do the Cooling pads make much difference?

Thanks.

Comment: You can try turning down the settings.  The cooling pad won't make a huge difference 2-3 degrees at the very most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

80 °C is nothing to worry about. You only need to be concerned if temperatures consistently reach 90 °C or higher. Modern GPUs are designed to operate at sustained temperatures of up to 95 °C ([just ask AMD](http://www.bit-tech.net/hardware/graphics/2013/10/28/is-the-amd-radeon-r9-290x-too-hot/)), with acceptable peak temperatures of up to 105 °C.

A cooling pad can help, especially if the air intake is from the bottom (which is how most laptops are designed). A well-designed cooling pad should be able to reduce temperatures by 5 °C or so when under load.

Comment: After looking on multiple forums, I think your answer is most helpful. Thanks.